# Laravel, @lang and strtolower()

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, lang

I'm trying to convert a string to lowercase like this:

```
@lang(strtolower('header.home'))
```

This not working. Any Idea? Thx.

Comment: You are lowering the argument (the translation dictionary key) of the translator function instead of  its output. Unfortunately, you can't do that with `@lang` because that will `echo` too, so you need to use `__()` or `trans()` then print it with `{{ }}` e.g. `{{ strtolower(trans('header.home')) }}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try this :

```
{{ strtolower(__('header.home')) }}
```

for more info :

You may retrieve lines from language files using the `__` helper function. The `__` method accepts the file and key of the translation string as its first argument. For example, let's retrieve the welcome translation string from the `resources/lang/messages.php` language file:

```
echo __('messages.welcome');

echo __('I love programming.');
```

Of course if you are using the Blade templating engine, you may use the {{ }} syntax to echo the translation string or use the @lang directive:

```
{{ __('messages.welcome') }}

@lang('messages.welcome')
```

If the specified translation string does not exist, the `__` function will simply return the translation string key. So, using the example above, the `__` function would return messages.welcome if the translation string does not exist.

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: I just edit the comment for more info about the __ helper :)

Comment: If you prefer verbosity you can use `{{ strtolower(trans('header.home')) }}`